# How many Youtube videos have more than 100 million views?

Tags: data-request, social-media, video

For at least a [billion views](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7VuK4dN6eJ3tR7zKE_LWCzXFlAMppXHI), I know that there are more than 400 videos. So there will probably be many thousands of videos with ay least 100M views. Where can I find the exact number?

Ideally, I would also like to see a complete list. I am prepared to spend some money on it.